# How to deploy a Pyramid app using pserve without installation?

Tags: python, pyramid, paster

I'm a beginner for Pyramid.

I want to deploy Pyramid to my production server.
I have a deploy script using Capistrano to do this.

```
set :pid_path, "/var/lib/#{application}"
set :log_path, "/var/log/#{application}"

namespace :deploy do

    task :restart, :roles => :app do
    end

    task :finalize_update, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{release_path} && python setup.py build"
        %w[ 5000 5001 ].each do |port|
            run "if [ -f #{pid_path}/#{port}.pid ]; then paster serve --stop-daemon --pid-file=#{pid_path}/#{port}.pid; fi"
            run "paster serve --daemon --pid-file=#{pid_path}/#{port}.pid --log-file=#{log_path}/paster.log #{release_path}/production.ini http_port=#{port}"
        end
    end

end
```

But it does not work without installation typing 'sudo python setup.py install'.
If I write code to do this, it might work but I don't want to do it because of permissions.

Does someone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, your best bet is to set up a [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) , activate it and then install the application in that `virtualenv` and run it from there :-)

Besides that there are options of using the setuptools/distutils to install into your local user folder by using the `--user` argument to easy_install as noted here: http://docs.python.org/install/index.html

But seriously, use virtualenv :-)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this option.
I consider to use virtualenv. (I have knew about this, but I don't want to use it.)
I should rewrite the deploy script.

Answer (score 4):

Either install the application into a virtualenv or use `python setup.py develop` which will link your project into the python environment (virtualenv or system depending on what python you invoked). This is usually preferable to `python setup.py install` because it keeps your source in a manageable location and doesn't require you to worry about manifest files to ensure that your static resources are in the installed bundle.